# Help with finding analytical formula of a recurrence relation using iteration.

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, geometric-series

$$\displaystyle{\displaylines{g(0)=1}}$$
$$\displaystyle{\displaylines{g(n)=3^n-g(n-1)+1}}$$

Find the analytical definition of the recurrence relation using iteration
$$\displaystyle{\displaylines{g_{1}=3^1-1+1=3}}$$
$$\displaystyle{\displaylines{g_{2}=3^2-(3-1+1)+1=3^2-3+1-1+1=7}}$$
$$\displaystyle{\displaylines{g_{3}=3^3-3^2+3-1+1-1+1=7}}$$
$$\displaystyle{\displaylines{g_{4}=3^4-3^3+3^2-3+1-1+1-1+1=21}}$$
$$\displaystyle{\displaylines{g_{5}=3^5-3^4+3^3-3^2-1+1-1+1-1+1=61}}$$

My Guess so far
$$\displaystyle{\displaylines{g(n)=3^n-3^{n-1}+3^{n-2}-3^{n-3}...+(-1)^n3^0}}$$
The problem I am having is figuring out what to do about the  +1 at the end.

Every even index n>0 ends with +1 and every odd index does not have a +1 at the end making it hard to use sum of geometric sequence.

Any ideas where to go from here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You don't have to guess. Eliminate $\,3^n\,$ between $\,g_n = 3^n - g_{n-1} + 1\,$ and $\,g_{n+1} = 3 \cdot 3^n - g_n + 1\,$ then you get a linear recurrence that can be solved with the usual methods.

Comment: The last term is either 0 or 1, you can write it as $1+(-1)^n$.

Comment: The geometric series has common factor $-1/3$