# Single Solution for this Recurrence: $a(n)=3^n-a(n-1)+1$

Tags: recurrence-relations

I've solved this recurrence using the iteration method for even and odd values of $n$, but I cannot seem to find a singular explicit function that solves this recurrence for all values of $n$.

The recurrence is
$$a(n) =
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $n=0$} \\
3^n-a(n-1)+1, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4456620/help-with-finding-analytical-formula-of-a-recurrence-relation-using-iteration) how to format the math. Then read the comments, too.

Comment: As a start, look at the generating function $G=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n$ and compute $G+xG$.

Comment: You know if you have found separate functions for even and odd say $f$ and $g$ respectively, you can always combine them as a single function given by $h(n) = \big(\frac{1 + (-1)^n}{2}\big) f(n) +  \big(\frac{1 - (-1)^n}{2}\big) g(n) $, which holds for both even and odd n.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way to solve it without particular/homogeneous solution. Note that $$(-1)^na_n-(-1)^{n-1}a_{n-1}=(-1)^n(3^n+1),$$ and telescope.

Comment: @lhf It actually is telescoping, you dont simplify the signs in LHS i.e. $(-1)^4a_4 - (-1)^3a_3 = f(3) $, and $$(-1)^3a_3 - (-1)^2a_2 = f(2) $$, you add them up to get $(-1)^4a_4 - (-1)^2a_2 = f(3) + f(2)$, and you can do this till 1.

Answer (score 2):

Let $A(x)=\sum_{n \ge 0} a_n x^n$ be the ordinary generating function. The recurrence and initial condition imply that
\begin{align}
A(x) 
&= a_0 x^0 + \sum_{n \ge 1} a_n x^n \\
&= 1 + \sum_{n \ge 1} (3^n - a_{n-1} + 1) x^n \\
&= 1 + \sum_{n \ge 1} (3x)^n - x \sum_{n \ge 1} a_{n-1} x^{n-1} + \sum_{n \ge 1} x^n \\
&= 1 + \frac{3x}{1-3x} - x A(x) + \frac{x}{1-x},
\end{align}
so
\begin{align}
A(x) 
&= \frac{1 + \frac{3x}{1-3x} + \frac{x}{1-x}}{1+x} \\
&= \frac{1 - 3x^2}{(1-x)(1+x)(1-3x)} \\
&= \frac{1/2}{1-x} - \frac{1/4}{1+x} + \frac{3/4}{1-3x} \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n\ge 0} x^n - \frac{1}{4}\sum_{n\ge 0} (-x)^n + \frac{3}{4}\sum_{n\ge 0} (3x)^n \\
&= \sum_{n\ge 0} \left(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{4} (-1)^n + \frac{3}{4} 3^n\right)x^n,
\end{align}
which immediately yields
$$a_n = \frac{2-(-1)^n+3^{n+1}}{4}.$$